# How can I center text/math inside a list environment?

Tags: equations, lists, horizontal-alignment

When using math (display) mode in conjunction with a list environment, the displayed material is not truly centered on the page; it is only centered with respect to the indentation of the item.  Consider the following example:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item The quadratic formula
\[
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\]
\item The freshman's dream
\[
(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n
\]
\end{itemize}
```

How can I get the displayed math to be centered horizontally with respect to the margins of the *page*??

Of course, this question is not specific to centering a displayed equation.  The same question is valid for the use of `\begin{center} text \end{center}` inside a list environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\def\MLine#1{\par\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{\[#1\]}}
\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

\begin{itemize}
\item The quadratic formula 
      \MLine{x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}
\item The freshman's dream 
      \MLine{(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n}
\end{itemize}

\[(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works as long as the itemize invironment isn't inside an itemize or enumerate or etc.  If you change \leftmargin to \@totalleftmargin, it will work more generally.

Comment: How can you use the MLine command with a gather environment?

Answer (score 2):

A crude solution is to put

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\displaybump}{\hbox to \@totalleftmargin{\hfil}}
\makeatother
```

into your preamble and then follow the content of each display with `\displaybump`, as in

```
\begin{itemize}
\item The quadratic formula
  \[
  x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \displaybump
  \]
\item The freshman's dream
  \[
  (a+b)^n=a^n+b^n \displaybump
  \]
\end{itemize}
```

Here's a complete LaTeX file showing (at least for me) that it works:

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
  \newcommand{\displaybump}{\hbox to \@totalleftmargin{\hfil}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Just for reference: The following is not inside an \texttt{itemize}:
\[
  x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\]

Just for reference: The following is not inside an \texttt{itemize}:
\[
  (a+b)^n=a^n+b^n
\]

\begin{itemize}
\item This item is so that the following \texttt{itemize} environment
  will have a larger total indentation.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item The quadratic formula:
    \[
    x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
    \]
  \item The quadratic formula, using \verb"\displaybump":
    \[
    x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \displaybump
    \]
  \item The freshman's dream:
    \[
    (a+b)^n=a^n+b^n
    \]
  \item The freshman's dream, using \verb"\displaybump":
    \[
    (a+b)^n=a^n+b^n \displaybump
    \]
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason, this does nothing on my end.

Comment: @Kristen Weird; I just tested it again, using copy and paste, and it works for me.  I added only `\documentclass{article}`. `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.  Are you sure it's not working? The difference in centering is very small; if you put your itemize inside of another itemize the difference is larger and slightly more visible.

Comment: @Kristen I edited my answer (above) to include a complete LaTeX file, which shows (at least to me) that it works.  (It's still a crude solution, though.)

Comment: @Kristen Oops; I'd left an extra `\displaybump` in there; I just corrected the LaTeX file.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it doesn't work.  I know the difference is very small, but the width of the object I want to display is so large that I can see a significant difference in white space on the left and right sides.