# Follow up Question: Label and Reference Equation inside Enumerate Environment

Tags: equations, lists, enumerate

I have seen the answers to [How can I center text/math inside a list environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11606/how-can-i-center-text-math-inside-a-list-environment/11675#11675). The accepted solution there, however, does not allow me to reference displayed equations. Another solution given there is a "crude" solution, requiring me to insert a command in each displayed equation.

Is there a way to modify the accepted solution to the above question so that displayed equations can be labelled and then referenced? (My MWE is similar to that presented in [answer to linked Q](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11675/15717))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're comfortable with the macro-use in [How can I center text/math inside a list environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11606/5764), then you could use

```
\def\NLine#1{\par\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}}}
```

This inserts the argument inside a numbered math display and allows referencing in the usual way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,bm}
\def\MLine#1{\par\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{\[#1\]}}
\def\NLine#1{\par\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}}}
\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

\begin{itemize}
\item The quadratic formula 
  \MLine{x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}
\item The freshman's dream
  \MLine{(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n}
\item The freshman's dream
  \NLine{(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n\label{xyz}}
\end{itemize}
See~\eqref{xyz}.

\[(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n\]

\end{document}
```

Perhaps a more intuitive definition might be

```
\makeatletter
\def\MLine{\par\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\@ifstar\MLineNoNum\MLineNum}
\def\MLineNoNum#1{\parbox{\textwidth}{\[#1\]}}
\def\MLineNum#1{\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}}}
\makeatother
```

that allows you to use `\MLine` for numbered equations and `\MLine*` for unnumbered ones (mirroring other numbered/unnumbered environments/macros).