# How to center gathered/aligned equations in enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11606/how-can-i-center-text-math-inside-a-list-environment) explains how to center single equations in the `enumerate` environment, but I'm not sure how to do the same thing with multiple equations (e.g., `gather` or `align`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also the `amsmath` environments are using TeX's `$$` display equations internally. The latter is using `\displaywidth` for the width of the equation and `\displayindent` for the left indentation of the equation. Both can be changed.
Thus the following example patches internal `amsmath` macros to add the settings:

```
\displaywidth=\textwidth
\displayindent=-\leftskip
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\start@gather{$$}{%
  $$%
  \displaywidth=\textwidth
  \displayindent=-\leftskip
}{}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \string\start@gather}}
\patchcmd\start@align{$$}{%
  $$%
  \displaywidth=\textwidth
  \displayindent=-\leftskip
}{}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \string\start@align}}
\patchcmd\start@multline{$$}{%
  $$%
  \displaywidth=\textwidth
  \displayindent=-\leftskip
}{}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \string\start@multline}}
\patchcmd\mathdisplay{$$}{%
  $$%
  \displaywidth=\textwidth
  \displayindent=-\leftskip
}{}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \string\mathdisplay}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  A=A
\end{gather}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hello
  \begin{gather}
    A=A
  \end{gather}
\item Hello
  \begin{align}
    A=A
  \end{align}
\item Hello
  \[
    A=A
  \]
\item Hello
  \begin{equation}
    A=A
  \end{equation}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Hello
    \begin{gather}
      A=A
    \end{gather}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Is there a way to disable these commands for a single list, while leaving them active for the rest of the document?

Comment: @fctaylor25 Then the redefinitions and the list should go into a local group between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.